# How do I get smooth lines in illustrator?

Tags: drawing, wacom

I got wacom intuos comic with the latest driver on it. In many tutorial that i saw, people create every time a new brush with pressure and the line looks like this:

[image]

But when I do the same exactly stuff, my like look like this:

[image]

Why are my lines not smooth, but thick at the end?

Comment: It's all in the brush you are using and its settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the brush you are using and its settings. You'll want to ignore pressure in favor of stroke profiles possibly.

If you *specifically* want a stroke that's narrow on both ends and wide in the middle, you can use the **Pencil Tool** to draw like a brush, but control the profile being applied to the stroke:

[image]

Just play with different tools and brushes until you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Illustrator makes nice brush strokes when the brush fits to drawn curves. There's two horizontal simple shapes made with the pen tool (actually they are the same, only width and fill are changed). Those shapes are dragged to brushes collection and defined to be artistic brushes.

The curved shapes are drawn with those two brushes. I used Wacom, but pressure is used to nothing. Wacom is so dammned good in filtering the stutter out that no smoothing was needed in Illustrator's brush tool options. If I tried the same with less forgiving tools, for ex. with a real brush and paint or in a computer with a brush that has in real time controlled width (=pressure or tilt), the life would be too short to recreate even these four shapes.

Do the same if you must get something usable today, but practice also with more responsive tools. They give infinitely more possiblities once you can control them.